# db migration from mac osx to linux

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql database in a mac osx server and I have transferred the database to a linux server using mysqldump.

Now I am seeing that the queries on linux server are not returning any values ( which work fine on mac os x ) .

On reading up on the manual I found that this behaviour has something to do with server system variable 'lower_case_table_names'.

I have it set as 2 on mac osx and 0 on the linux server ( default values ).

The documentation suggests that I keep the value as 1 in case the server enviroments are windows and linux. ( I have a mac osx / linux combination )

Has anyone done this type of migration ? If yes , can you please give me some pointers as to how I should go about doing this.

Best Regards

Comment: the simple way is to get ride of capital letters in table names and queries, other than that do what it says and change to 1 (where case is irrelevant)

Comment: Thanks Abe,

I have it working now. These were the steps I took to get it working.

On mac server:
mysqldump mydb > mydbDump.sql

On Linux server:
mysql> create database mydb;

edit /etc/my.cnf and add the line
set-variable=lower_case_table_names=1

 /etc/init.d/mysqld restart

/usr/local/mysql -u root -pmyPassword myDb < mydbDump.sql

This made sure that the mysql stores all the table names in lower case when it runs the create table command.

I could have run a small sql to rename the tables, I just wanted mysql to do it on its own